# CustomAdapter - CheckedTextView

Tags: android, custom-adapter, checkedtextview

I have a problem with "remembering" states of Checkboxes in CheckTextView.
Now when I click, it changes the state but on different CheckBox.

```
class CustomAdapterSmartwatch extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


static class ViewHolder {
    protected CheckedTextView cTextView;
}

ViewHolder holder;


public CustomAdapterSmartwatch(Context context, ArrayList<String> variables) {
    super(context,R.layout.row_smartwatch_resources,variables);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater smartwatchinflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = smartwatchinflater.inflate(R.layout.row_smartwatch_resources,parent,false);
        holder.cTextView = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_smartwatch_checked);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.cTextView.setText(getItem(position));

    holder.cTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.cTextView.isChecked()) {
                holder.cTextView.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                holder.cTextView.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Now i'm trying to figure out with using Holder but i heard that it's possible to use SparseBooleanArray. Can someone explain how to make it works?

**EDIT 1**
Ok, I have ListView which is controlled by CustomAdapter. That adapter contains only 1 item (CheckedTextView).
The problem is that after scrolling these checkedboxes don't remember their state.
I saw your answer with explanation but now after clicking any "CheckedTextView", the state of their checkbox doesn't change.

**EDIT 2**

```
    @NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater smartwatchinflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = smartwatchinflater.inflate(R.layout.row_smartwatch_resources,parent,false);
        holder.cTextView = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_smartwatch_checked);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.cTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("MainActivity","Position = " + position);
            CheckedTextView checkedText = (CheckedTextView) v;
            checkedState.put(position, !checkedText.isChecked());

            Log.d("MainActivity","State = " + checkedState.get(position));

        }
    });

    holder.cTextView.setText(getItem(position));
    holder.cTextView.setChecked(checkedState.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

**EDIT 3**

```
class CustomAdapterSmartwatch extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public SparseBooleanArray checkedState = new SparseBooleanArray();
private CheckedTextView cTextView;


public CustomAdapterSmartwatch(Context context, ArrayList<String> variables) {
    super(context,R.layout.row_smartwatch_resources,variables);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater smartwatchinflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    convertView = smartwatchinflater.inflate(R.layout.row_smartwatch_resources,parent,false);
    cTextView = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_smartwatch_checked);

    cTextView.setText(getItem(position));
    cTextView.setChecked(checkedState.get(position));

    cTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("MainActivity","Position = " + position);
            CheckedTextView checkedText = (CheckedTextView) v;
            checkedText.toggle();

            if (checkedText.isChecked())
                checkedState.put(position,true);
            else
                checkedState.delete(position);
            Log.d("MainActivity","State = " + checkedState.get(position));

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: Your edit is more appropriate as a comment to my answer or as a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep a boolean flag for each CheckTextView. This can be an array, List, or SparseBooleanArray. The data structure you choose should be a field of your adapter:

```
class CustomAdapterSmartwatch extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private SparseBooleanArray checkedState = new SparseBooleanArray();

    // ...
}
```

You do not want to put it in the holder because the holder is retired only fr visible rows. On the other hand, you want to maintain the checked state for every row, visible or not.

Now, you set the stored checked state when the user clicks on a `CheckedTextView`:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // ...

    holder.cTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckedTextView checkedText = (CheckedTextView)v;
            checkedState.put(position, checkedText.isChecked());
        }
    });
}
```

And you restore the checked state whenever you inflate a view or reuse one from a holder:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // ...

    holder.cTextView.setText(getItem(position));
    holder.cTextView.setChecked(checkedState.get(position));

    // ...
}
```

Comment: @Ace Currently my answer is the "top" answer when I load this page. Note that SO reorders answers based on votes and randomizes those that tie.

Comment: I meant that post where I asked a question ;)

Comment: CheckedTextView checkedText = (CheckedTextView)v;
            checkedState.put(position, v.isChecked());

It shouldn't be checked "State.put(position, checkedText.isChecked());" ?

Comment: @Ace What is `State` in your suggested change?

Comment: @Ace I am unsure if `onClick()` is called before or after Android sets the state of the `CheckedTextView`. If it is called before, then you will need to change `checkedText.isChecked()` in my answer to `!checkedText.isChecked()`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - checkedState.
A change applies to v.isChecked() to checkedText.isChecked()

Comment: @Ace Oh, right. `v.isChecked()` should cause a compiler error. That was the whole point of the cast and `checkedText`.

Comment: I made Edit 2.
And here i have 2 problems. Now value of checkedState doesn't change (always true). And checkboxes do not change their state to checked.

Comment: Ok, it works now. I deleted using ViewHolder and in OnClick implementation I put checkedtext.toogle();
And if condition - if it's checked - it will be added into SparseBooleanArray.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: @Ace removing the ViewHolder does not sound like a good idea. Manually toggling the checkbox might be required despite my assumptions. The checkedState array should be changed to match the actual state of the checkbox. This means you should not use an if statement.

Comment: on EDIT 3 I have an actual code. May you tell me if it needed any "fixes"?

Comment: EDIT2 contains the code which I think you have on mind. But it didn't work properly. States were always true and checkboxes never set their marks on true.

Comment: @Ace does edit work? You only need `checkedState.put(position, checkedText.isChecked());` rather than an if statement. But it should not make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your code with following update:

```
class CustomAdapterSmartwatch extends ArrayAdapter<CustomAdapterSmartwatch.MyPojo> {

    class MyPojo {
        boolean checked;
        String data;

        public boolean isChecked() {
            return checked;
        }

        public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
            this.checked = checked;
        }

        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected CheckedTextView cTextView;
    }

    ViewHolder holder;


    public CustomAdapterSmartwatch(Context context, ArrayList<MyPojo> variables) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_smartwatch_resources, variables);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public MyPojo getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater smartwatchinflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = smartwatchinflater.inflate(R.layout.row_smartwatch_resources,parent,false);
            holder.cTextView = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_smartwatch_checked);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final MyPojo item = getItem(position);

        holder.cTextView.setText(item.getData());
        holder.cTextView.setChecked(item.isChecked());

        holder.cTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean nextStatus = !item.isChecked();
                item.setChecked(nextStatus);
                holder.cTextView.setChecked(nextStatus);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(Context,int,ArrayList<String>)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; ArrayList<String> cannot be converted to int)
constructor

But ArrayList<String> cannot be changed.

Comment: Change constructor to `CustomAdapterSmartwatch(Context context, ArrayList<MyPojo> variables) `

Comment: Please explain how your changes to the OP's code will solve his problem.

Comment: For keeping changes in adapter you must save status in item model. I'm doing the same. Any query?

Comment: You should edit your question to include your explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the view in onClick() method itself.

```
holder.cTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v instanceOf CheckedTextView) {
                CheckedTextView c = (CheckedTextView) v;
                c.setChecked(!c.isChecked());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: There is no reason to do `instanceOf` since you only set this listener for CheckedTextView instances. Also, CheckedTextView already keeps track of its own checked state when clicked. There is no reason to write any code to do so.